# Python bulk renamer works, but doesn't work at the same time?

Tags: python, python-2.7

when I run the program from the command line I get no errors and it seems to execute, but nothing happens! I'm ready to stab my eyes out from staring at code for so long. I just want this to work so I can turn it in and be done with this assignment.

The program is supposed to run as follows.

python bulk.py (directory name) (name for files)

```
import os
import sys
import random


def filterByExtension(root, allfiles, extensions):
  matching = []
  ext = []
  for i in allfiles:
    name = i
    dot = name.rfind('.')
    ext = name[dot+1:].lower()
    if ext not in extensions:
      continue
    path = os.path.join(root, name)
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
      print "Warning: File type not expected"
      continue
      if os.path.isfile(path):
        matching.append(name)
  return matching    

def sortByMTime(path, matching):
  presort = []
  for file in matching:
    path = os.path.join(path, file)
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(path)
    presort.append((mtime, file))
    presort.sort()
  return presort
  print "Here is the presorted shtuff",presort


def assignNames(prefix, inorder):
  count = ''
  digits = 0
  count = str(len(inorder))
  digits = len(count)
  template = '%%0%dd' % digits
  newnames = {}
  count = 0
  for i in inorder:
    count += 1
    s = template % count
    newnames[i[1]] = prefix+s+'.'+i[1].split('.')[1]
  return newnames
  print "Here are the new names that will be used",newnames


def makeTempName(allfiles):
  n = random.randint(1, 1000000000)
  t = '__temp' + str(n) + '__'
  while t in allfiles:
    n += 1
    t = '__temp' + str(n) + '__'
  return t



def makeScript(inorder, newnames, tempname):
  script = []
  print
  print "a" 
  print
  for elt in inorder:
    print 
    print "b"
    print
    chain = []
    inthechain = {}
    if elt not in newnames:
      continue
    if newnames[elt] == elt:
      del newnames[elt]
      continue
    if newnames[elt] not in newnames:
      print "This is the script output inside the if statement:"
      print script
      script.append( (elt,newnames[elt]) )
      del newnames[elt]
      continue
    else:
      link = elt
      while True:
        target = newnames[elt]
        chain.append( (link,target) )
        inthechain[link] = True
        link = target
        if link not in newnames:
          break 

        chain.reverse()
        print "this is the chain output before loop:"
    print chain
    for ( a, b ) in chain:
          print "This is the output of chain:"
          print chain
          script.append( a, b )
          del newnames[a]


          print 'here is the inthechain output in function'
          print inthechain
          print '=========================================='

          print 'here is the inorder output in function'
          print inorder
          print '=========================================='

          print 'here is the newnames output in function'
          print newnames
          print '=========================================='

          print 'here is the tempname output in function'
          print tempname
          print '=========================================='

          print 'here is the script output in function'
          print script
          print '=========================================='
  return script




def doRenames(pathfull, script):
  for entry in script:
    print entry[0], '->', entry[1]
    oldpath = os.path.join(path, entry[0])
    newpath = os.path.join(path, entry[1])
    if os.path.exists(newpath):
      print 'Error: file name already exists.'
      os.exit(1)
    else:
      os.rename(oldpath, newpath)




def main():
  directory = []
  prefix = []
  path = []
  tempname = []
  if len(sys.argv) <= 1 or len(sys.argv) > 3:
    print "You have messed up, please check your arguments again"
    sys.exit(1)

  elif len(sys.argv) == 3:    
    directory = sys.argv[1]
    path = os.path.abspath(directory)
    dirname = os.path.basename(path)
    print "Directory: ", sys.argv[1:-1]
    print "Prefix: ", sys.argv[-1]
    allfiles = []
    allfiles = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])
    print allfiles
    extensions = []
    extensions = ['jpeg','jpg','png','gif']
    matching = filterByExtension(path, allfiles, extensions)
    inorder = sortByMTime(path, matching)
    newnames = assignNames(prefix, inorder)
    tempname = makeTempName(allfiles)
    script = makeScript(inorder, newnames, tempname)
    renamed = doRenames(path, script)

  else:
    directory = sys.argv[1]
    path = os.path.abspath(directory)
    dirname = os.path.basename(path)    
    print "Directory: ", path
    print "Prefix: ", dirname









main()
```

Comment: My assignment instructions if it helps. [link](http://cit.dixie.edu/cs/1410/asst_bulkrename.html)

Comment: Have you narrowed it down to any specific area of the code? There is a lot here to have to read.

Comment: Can you narrow it down? One key to debugging is isolating bugs by differentiating working code from broken code. What works, and where do things go wrong?

Comment: I had everything working until I after writing the sorting function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No file names will ever be added to `matching` here:

```
if not os.path.isfile(path):
  print "Warning: File type not expected"
  continue
  if os.path.isfile(path):
    matching.append(name)
```

Probably you wanted to have the second `if` in the outer block, not indented under the first `if`:

```
if not os.path.isfile(path):
  print "Warning: File type not expected"
  continue
if os.path.isfile(path):
  matching.append(name)
```

Or, simpler:

```
if not os.path.isfile(path):
  print "Warning: File type not expected"
else:
  matching.append(name)
```

Comment: Ahhhh, yes. Thank you. It is stupid little errors like this I am completely missing! Thank you.

Comment: 'I'm ready to stab my eyes out from staring at code for so long' ..and trivially found with pdb or other debugger:((  You must learn to debug, else there is no point continuing with software development:(  Please point out to your prof/tutor that their course needs attention.  First, 'Hello World', second, 'How to debug' and third, 'Write stuff with more than one line'.